# I'm having trouble lining up Text boxes in css

Tags: css, layout

im having trouble lining up some textboxes in css/html my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CTF Scoreboard</title>
    <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img class="headerimg" src="img/header.png" />
        <form action="search.php" method="get" class="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search players" required          class="box" name="user" />
            <input name="submit" type="image" src="img/blank.png" class="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
body{
margin: 0px;
}
.header{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
margin: 0px;
background-image:url('img/headerbg.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
}

.headerimg{
height: 90px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

.header .search{
padding:0px;
background-image: url('img/searchbox.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 310px;
height: 40px;
position:absolute;
top:27px;
right:27px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header .search .box{
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 260px;
height: 37px;
}

.header .search .submit{
border: 0px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 3px;

width: 36px;
height: 36px;
}
```

What it currently looks like: `http://84.80.135.87/scoreboard%20th%20ctf/`

i really don't see why this is not working, it is just ignoring the margins.
i have tested this in Firefox and Chrome, it works in neither

Comment: Hi, you can use table to align your textboxes.

Comment: You could also just set the textbox's border & color rather then aligning it to a background rectangle

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the vertical alignment of your image input field. It is aligned relative to the other inline elements in the line (in this case your text input field) the same way an image would - the bottom of the image is aligned with the baseline of the text. To fix this, alter your CSS as follows:

```
.header .search .submit{
border: 0px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-top: 3px;
vertical-align: top; /* Modify the vertical alignment. */    
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
.header .search .box 
{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 37px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 260px;
    display:block;
}
```